# Python list automatically updated when the variable fetching the value is modified

Tags: python, list, reference

I have the following code snippet. I wanted to only update the list stored inside the variable `test_list` but not the original `addStartAndEnd` list. But every time I modify the `test_list`, surprisingly the original `addStartAndEnd` list gets updated and reflects the change!

My question is, I didn't do anything with the original `addStartAndEnd` list. I just fetched the last item of this list, stored it inside `test_list` and tried to modify it. So how is the `addStartAndEnd` list getting updated? Is this how Python functions such that every time the reference it points to gets updated it automatically modifies itself? What's the trick? Please assist.

Attached  is the code:

```
addStartAndEnd = [[1, 2, 3, 4]]  #the original list
temp_list = [-3, -2]
addStartAndEnd.append(temp_list)
test_list = addStartAndEnd[-1]  #fetching the last item
test_list.append(-999)   #appending a value only to test_list, nothing to do with addStartAndEnd
print("Final and test lists are:", test_list, addStartAndEnd)
```

Output is:

```
Final and test lists are: [-3, -2, -999] [[1, 2, 3, 4], [-3, -2, -999]]
```

-999 appended to the last item of the `addStartAndEnd` list fetched inside the variable `test_list`.

Comment: Did you mean: `test_list=addStartAndEnd[-1][:]`? This makes a copy of the last element.

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: thank you so much people @quamrana, but I wonder what's the difference between addStartAndEnd[-1][:] and addStartAndEnd[-1]?

Comment: Its what I said. `addStartAndEnd[-1]` is just a reference to the last element. `addStartAndEnd[-1][:]` is a reference to a copy of the last element.